# Everything showing temporarily in button click function

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the JS code:

```
const submit = document.getElementById("submitBtn")
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const toF = document.getElementById("toFahrenheit")
const toC = document.getElementById("toCelsius")
const result = document.getElementById("result")

let temp;

submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (toF.checked) {
        temp = Number(input.value);
        temp = temp * 9 / 5 + 32;
        result.textContent = temp.toFixed(1) + "F°"
    } else  if(toC.checked) {
        temp = Number(input.value);
        temp = (temp - 32) * (5/9);
        result.textContent = temp.toFixed(1) + "C°"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").classList.remove("visually-hidden")
    }
})
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
        <br>
        <form action="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="title">
                    Temperature converter
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="result">
                    0
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="radio" id="toCelsius" name="Temperature">
                    <label for="toCelsius" id="toCelsiusLabel">Fahrenheit➡️Celsius</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="radio" id="toFahrenheit" name="Temperature">
                    <label for="toFahrenheit" id="toFahrenheitLabel">Celsius➡️Fahrenheit</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Temperature" id="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button id="submitBtn">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger visually-hidden" role="alert" id="error">
                        Please choose a unit.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

the result as well as the error are both showing up for a brief second after clicking the submit button.

I'm expecting the error or result (depending on situation) to show up and change only when the button is clicked again. I haven't tried anything else since i'm pretty new to code and this is basically the only way i know. Please help.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you [edit] your post by adding part of your HTML code to make [mre] ?

Comment: The errors disappear because it's submitting the form anyway.  What are you expecting `submit.onclick.function();` to do? What is `submit`?